# wp7 SoundEffect play binding to scrollbar

Tags: binding, windows-phone-7, audio, scrollbar

I'm wandering how to play music and show the current playing time on scrollbar. I'm using the SoundEffectInstance class because I play it from  MemoryStream.

pleas help me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer which you start when you start playing the sound/music.

You can then use this timer to show elapsed time. If you know the length of the music you can also calculate the remaining time.

Be sure to account for pausing and stopping the timer when the user pauses and stops the music (if applicable). Also be sure to pause and save the current elapsed time appropriately when tombstoned.